# Add/Remove class on scroll depending on scroll length

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am a jQuery beginner and would like some pointers on whether the following code could be made shorter, or there is a better way to get the same result.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
     var aa=jQuery('#navigation-wrapper');
     var bb=jQuery('#top');
     jQuery(window).scroll(function(){

        if(jQuery("body").hasClass("home")){    
            if(jQuery(this).scrollTop()>510){
                aa.addClass("navbar-fixed-top");
                //bb.css('marginTop', aa.height());
             }
            else{
                aa.removeClass("navbar-fixed-top");
                //bb.css('marginTop', 0);
            }
        }
        else {
           if(jQuery(this).scrollTop()>293){
             aa.addClass("navbar-fixed-top");
           //bb.css('marginTop', aa.height());
            }
            else{
                aa.removeClass("navbar-fixed-top");
                //bb.css('marginTop', 0);
            }
        }
     });
  });
```

Comment: As we all want to make our code more efficient or improve it in one way or another, **try to write a title that summarizes what your code does**, not what you want to get out of a review. Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review - Asking Questions](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/2438/41243) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code can made very short.

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var scrollTop = $(document.body).hasClass('home') ? 510 : 293;
    $('#navigation-wrapper').toggleClass('navbar-fixed-top', $(this).scrollTop() > scrollTop);
});
```

1. There is no need of wrapping the code in `$(document).ready()` for binding events on `window`.
2. Use [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)
3. Use [`toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/#toggleClass-className-state) with second parameter to add/remove class based on a condition.

Comment: Did you just suggest the asker to go somewhere else, while at the same time preventing him with your answer from deleting his question? That's not ideal.

Comment: @JanDvorak No. I flagged the question for mod attention and asked them to migrate to CR.SE.

Comment: Understood. A better option would have been to suggest the asker to delete the question and reask it somewhere else. That way the mods don't have to get involved.

Comment: @JanDvorak Right. That'll decrease burden on busy mods. Thanks. Will keep it in mind. :)

Comment: Does this not mean that the condition would only run if the body has a class of "home"?

Comment: forget that, just re-read the link to ternary operator